# Why is $i$ a removable singularity of $\frac{\sin(z-i)}{z^2+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Why is $i$ a removable singularity of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z-i)}{z^2+1}$? We can find the Taylor expansions of the $\sin(z-i)$ and $\frac{1}{z+i}$ to get the Laurent series (actually Taylor series since $i$ is removable) of $f(z)$ for $0<|z-i|<2$, but is there another way to show that $f$ is removable?

Comment: $$f(z) = \frac{\sin(z-i)}{z^{2}+1} = \frac{\sin(z-i)}{z-i} \cdot \frac{1}{z+i}$$ and use that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

Comment: @Mattos I use Complex Variables and Applications by Brown and Churchill, and it seems that they don't introduce this method. What is this?

Comment: What method? I just used some algebraic manipulation and applied [a very well known limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Comment: @Mattos "A discontinuity of a function is removable if the limit of the function exists at that point" stated by Carmeister in the answer. Brown and Churchill might state it in a different way, but I don't know where do the place this statement in the book...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a discontinuity of a function is removable if the limit of the function exists at that point. So any method of showing that
$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\sin(z-i)}{z^2+1}$$
exists will do the trick.

As Mattos notes in a comment, one way to do so is write $z^2+1=(z+i)(z-i)$ and then use the fact that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\sin(z-i)}{z^2+1}=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\sin(z-i)}{z-i}\times\frac1{z+i}=\frac1{2i}$$and [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem).